# get both - download link and link to view in the browser from s3 bucket using aws sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The image which I want to fetch from s3 bucket will have two purposes:

1. To be available for download
2. To be overlayed on google maps using google maps api for javascript

For the 2nd puropse it is necessary to have a link of the image which is displayed in the browser as given in the docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

```
   var historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
        'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
        imageBounds);
    historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
```

But I also want a link from which the user can download the image.

I am using presigned URLs for fetching the URLs of the image files by using the following code:

```
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,

})
```

I read that if I want the link to be be displayed in the browser instead of being downloaded then I will have to set the contentType as image/png. But if I do so, then I am not able to get the download link.

I want to know if there is a way to accomplish both the tasks.

I am using Angular 4 with nodeJs back end for this project.

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the response's content type by using the `ResponseContentType` parameter of the `getObject` function:

```
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
    ResponseContentType: "image/png",

})
```

Comment: More correct would be to always store the object with an accurate `Content-Type`, but to use some variant of `ResponseContentDisposition: "attachment"` to trigger a download, don't you think?